# How to format time with moment.js zone() method?

Tags: momentjs

I am using moment.js v2.5, `utcOffset` is not available in v2.5. I only get the current user's `Time.now.utc_offset //19800`(UTC offset for
 India) from rails backend.

1. Why does `zone()` and `utcOffset()` return opposite values of each other (check the snippet of code included)?
2. How to calculate proper time with `zone()` method in moment.js ?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  moment.suppressDeprecationWarnings = true
  $('.utc span').text(moment().utcOffset());
  $('.zone span').text(moment().zone());
  
  // 19800/60 => 330
  $('.india.zone span').text(moment(1519043028734).zone(330).format('HH:mm'))
  $('.india.utc span').text(moment(1519043028734). utcOffset(330).format('HH:mm'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<p class="zone">Zone: <span></span></p>
<p class="utc">UTC: <span></span></p>
<p class="india zone">Zone:<span></span></p>
<p class="india utc">UTC:<span></span></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`utcOffset`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/):

> Get the UTC offset in minutes.
>
> **Note**: Unlike [`moment.fn.zone`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/timezone-offset/) this function returns the real offset from UTC, not the reverse offset (as returned by `Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset`).

So, basically, [`zone()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/timezone-offset/) has the same output of [`Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset):

> The time-zone offset is the difference, in minutes, between UTC and local time. Note that this means that the offset is positive if the local timezone is behind UTC and negative if it is ahead. For example, for time zone UTC+10:00 (Australian Eastern Standard Time, Vladivostok Time, Chamorro Standard Time), -600 will be returned.

To get *proper time* with `zone()` you can simply change sign to your offset (e.g. `-330` instead of `300`)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  moment.suppressDeprecationWarnings = true
  $('.utc span').text(moment().utcOffset());
  $('.zone span').text(moment().zone());
  
  // 19800/60 => 330
  $('.india.zone span').text(moment(1519043028734).zone(330*-1).format('HH:mm'))
  $('.india.utc span').text(moment(1519043028734). utcOffset(330).format('HH:mm'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<p class="zone">Zone: <span></span></p>
<p class="utc">UTC: <span></span></p>
<p class="india zone">Zone:<span></span></p>
<p class="india utc">UTC:<span></span></p>
```